# running python script under httpd_t SELinux context

Tags: python, selinux

I have a python script, running as a systemd unit, that I need to run in the httpd_t SELinux context under the nginx user, I have tried using runcon but it says that the transition is not allowed and if I allow the transition using audit2allow it then denies the python3 entry point and I am not willing to give httpd_t access to bin_t. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a custom policy that allows `unconfined_service_t` to transition to `httpd_t` and using a shebang indicating the the script was a python script to not need to specify `/usr/bin/python3` in the `ExecStart` command thus eliminating my `bin_t` issues.

Answer (score 0):

`init_t` can execute `httpd_exec_t`, and `httpd_exec_t` can transition to `httpd_t`.
So you should be able to do what you want with:

```bash
semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_exec_t '/usr/bin/yourscript.py'
restorecon -RF /usr/bin/yourscript.py
```

You might need some booleans too, you'll see if it is needed with `audit2allow -a`.

ref. [1](https://access.redhat.com/blogs/766093/posts/1976233), [2](https://lists.fedoraproject.org/archives/list/selinux@lists.fedoraproject.org/thread/WLUTWZACZ4TQKWBXIIGOEKB6A3ISBVBE/), [3](https://linux.die.net/man/8/httpd_selinux)

Comment: how would I go about transitioning `httpd_exec_t` to `httpd_t` in python? I can't seem to find any information on it